# dplyr and "is.data.frame(df) is not true" error

Tags: r, dplyr

getting "is.data.frame(df) is not true" error after "create lagged..." line, cannot figure out why. Any help would be appreciated!
    ```{r, echo=TRUE}

````
df1 <- read.dta("~/Downloads/doesoil clean.dta")
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)

str(df1)


```

```{r, echo=TRUE}

## Create lagged outcome variable for policy
df1 <- arrange(data, cty_name, year)
df1 <- group_by(data, cty_name) %>%
    mutate(
           oil_L1 = lag(oil, 1),
              regime1_L1 = lag(regime1, 1)   ,     
               islam_L1 = lag(islam, 1)    ,    
              metal_L1 = lag(metal, 1)   , 
                log135_L1 = lag(log135, 1)   , 

            )

df1$log_oil_L1<-log(df1$oil_L1+.001)

df1<-dplyr::select(df1,
        cty_name, 
        year,
        regime1,#  regime type , 1=Democracy
        regime1_L1, ## Lagged regime type
        oil_L1,## oil exports as percentage of GDP (lagged)
        log_oil_L1,## Logged oil exports (lagged)
        islam_L1,## percent islam (lagged)
        metal_L1,##  mineral exports as percentage of GDP (lagged)
        mideast,##  dummy if country is in the middle east
        log135,## Logged per capita income
        log135_L1) ## Logged per capita income (lagged)

df1$year<-as.numeric(df1$year)
```
````

Attempting to subset the data with the notated specifications, it was provided by the professor as a starting point but I'm having issues debugging.

Comment: If you're trying to sort/arrange your `df1`, then why are you referencing `data`? Perhaps just `arrange(df1, cty_name, year)` will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you are referencing a variable not defined in the code you shared with us, "data". As mentioned by r2evans in a comment, using the data.frame you've assigned to the name df1 should solve your problem.